# React-linkify doesn’t highlight the urls of the child component

Tags: reactjs

Using React Linkify to highlight the URLs in the Linki component @ https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nlxodz. I was curious and wanted to experiment with the package and stumbled across one issue where if we include a component as a child of Linkify, it won't highlight any URLs of the child. is there a possible solution to highlight the text of the child component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wrap your subcomponent with linkify

```
const WontDisplay=()=>{
  return (
   <Linkify>
     <u><span> http://random.org</span></u>
   </Linkify>
  )
}
```

Comment: however, if we have multiple conditions inside the child then we have to wrap all of them with linkify. This seems to be the only solution as of now.